# Using IDFI (Identifier for Information) in iOS App for Custom User Tracking

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hi Stack Overflow community,

I'm currently working on an iOS app and I'm interested in implementing custom user tracking using the IDFI (Identifier for Information) provided by Apple. While I've reviewed Apple's documentation, I still have some uncertainties.

Has anyone had experience working with IDFI and could guide me on how to integrate it into my app? I'm looking to understand how to retrieve the IDFI value and leverage it for tracking user interactions within the app. Are there any important considerations or best practices I should be aware of when using IDFI?

Thank you all for taking the time to read my question and provide assistance!
"https://auction.unityads.unity3d.com/v6/test/games/5383517/requests?idfi=06db8844-bfed-47a3-b768-b74b0184369d&advertisingTrackingId=668827DD-2ABC-405D-B9F3-AC1C53511AD7&limitAdTracking=false "

Comment: Please post a link to Apple's documentation.